# In python ephem I am unable to get position's of certain constellations

Tags: python, pyephem

```
import ephem

date = '2018/9/20'

sun = ephem.Sun()
sun.compute(date)
print 'Sun in', list(ephem.constellation(sun))[1]

moon = ephem.Moon()
moon.compute(date)
print 'Moon in', list(ephem.constellation(moon))[1]

mars = ephem.Mars()
mars.compute(date)
print 'Mars in', list(ephem.constellation(mars))[1]

mercury = ephem.Mercury()
mercury.compute(date)
print 'Mercury in', list(ephem.constellation(mercury))[1]

jupiter = ephem.Jupiter()
jupiter.compute(date)
print 'Jupiter in', list(ephem.constellation(jupiter))[1]

venus = ephem.Venus()
venus.compute(date)
print 'Venus in', list(ephem.constellation(venus))[1]

saturn = ephem.Saturn()
saturn.compute(date)
print 'Saturn in', list(ephem.constellation(saturn))[1]
```

I have found the all 7 planets in their house for the specific date. Now I am in need to find the Rahu and Ketu house in a astro table. How to get that? Is there any functions for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quite sure that only *real* planets are available in `ephem`. I found this definition

> Astronomically, Rahu and Ketu denote the points of intersection of the
>   paths of the Sun and the Moon as they move on the celestial sphere.

Using some math will tell you the points. Maybe [this](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/coordinates) might help you to transform the coordinates between the different systems.

From that you could derive a view point in `ephem`, it is called an [`Observer`](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/quick.html#observers) and pass it to `ephem.constellation(o)`,

Comment: Actually, ephem is astronomy and i am going for astrology, it seems to be the best answer for astronpmy

Comment: Not sure if there is a package for astrology in Python. Have you found one?

Comment: Yes, I found it. pyswisseph is the package and we can import it as "import swisseph as swe"